# Why does WrapPanel breaks Grid's ColumDefinitions?

Tags: wpf

This is a design I use often, a grid with columns of relative sizes (using the asterisk for width) so to mimic relative margins or other similar task.

An example of something similar to what I'm working on right now:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="AAA" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is its output

[image]

which is exactly what I expected.

But, if I just change the root Grid with a WrapPanel, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<WrapPanel>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="AAA" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
    </Grid>
</WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

then I get this:

[image]

Ok, there is obviously some difference in placement due to the WrapPanel layout system, and this is ok to me and even expected, but...what the heck it's happening to the columns?

Answer (score 0):

The relative size of the columns cannot be calculated unless the `Grid` actually has a `Width`. I am not sure why you want to use a `WrapPanel` here but you could specify a fixed `Width` or `MinWidth` of the `Grid`:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="True"
          Width="300">
```

Comment: Yes, ok, but it's an explanation that do not hold ground: the grid **get** a width, at a certain point. The Measure/Arrange system can even do 10 passes, but still the grid ActualWidth property is set and updated, and internally on the Resize it is supposed to recalculate the columns width. As simple as it gets, is has no width set by me when hosted inside a wrap panel and when hosted inside a grid, a stack panel, or a ContentPresenter, or a border, or a dock panel. The same conditions, and it works as expected in all cases apart when hosted into a Wrap Panel. Why?